# How many Max client can i connect to server in socket programming

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

1. I am writing socket client and server program . Now i have a question 
   that how many MAX client can i connect to the server , because accept system call returning new file descriptor whose entry is storing in  file 
   descriptor table and MAX file descriptor is 1024.  so is MAX client is 1024?
2. If max client is limited and all client  are connected to server, in this case server will not accept any new connection, and some of the client  are only connecting and not doing any operation. How to identify such client and close the connection between them to accept new conncetion again.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of file descriptors is going to depend on the OS you are using -- different OS's will have different limits.  If you need to, you may be able to raise the limit for your process by using the `ulimit` bash command, or by having your process call `setrlimit()`.  (see this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75996/modify-ulimit-open-files-of-a-specific-process?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for details)

As for your second question about identifying idle clients -- one way to do it would be to keep a last-activity-timestamp associated with each socket, and update it to the current time any time you `send()` or `recv()` any bytes on that socket.  Then if/when you need to free up some sockets, you can start by closing the socket(s) with the smallest last-activity-timestamp values.

Comment: If he's using blocking I/O he can just set some read timeout like a minute or two and drop the connection if it times out reading the next request.

Comment: True, although a blocking I/O program that is also hitting the maximum-file-descriptors limit seems unlikely; it would either be using a thread-per-socket (in which case it would probably have hit the maximum-threads limit first), or it would be blocking on one socket and ignoring all the others (which doesn't seem like useful behavior)